# How to (blur) element in angular except when it's clicked in child elements

Tags: angular

How do I use blur, but not activate blur when it's clicked in the child elements?
I can't trigger the click event on the `li` element.

```html
<div class="select-menu">
  <div class="selected" tabindex="0" (blur)="showList = false" (click)="showList = !showList"><span>{{selected}}</span></div>
  <ng-container *ngIf="showList">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of list; let i=index" (click)="selectItem(item, i)">
        <span>{{item}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please give more information on what you want to achieve? Probably the result or something. Or some stackblitz demo reproducing your problem

Comment: When a user click on let's say a button. A list will be activated and showen. This list has to dissapear when the user clicks outside this list. But the problem is that when the user clicks inside the list it also activated the blur event. And that's what I want to prevent.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a "click outside box must close the box" like a popup then you can register a `click` listener on `document` and determine if the click is outside of your box zone :

```
export class BoxComponent {

    openedBox = false;

    @ViewChild('box', { read: ElementRef }) boxRef: ElementRef;

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    clickOutsideCurrentPopup(event: Event) {
        if (this.openedBox) {
            // if clicked outside only
            if (!this.boxRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
                this.openedBox = false; // or do whatever you want to close your box
            }
        }
        // else is already closed, do nothing
    }
}
```